# ReportViewer 11.0 not loading in form but below winform

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, reportserver

This has me really stumped.  I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2 with SSRS and Visual Studio 2013.  The application is written in VB.Net.  When I create a report on the server and then try to incorporate it into my application with a ReportViewer the ReportViews shows up below the form and not within the form.  When executed as a remote report nothing shows.  The report works find in Report Server.  When ReportViewer is added to form it is loaded below the form and not IN the form and the options are set for a Server Report.  The ReportViewer is version 11.  I don't know how this is happening now and not before.  I have 2 reports from before as I was developing that seem to work ok and now I'm trying to add more and it's not working.  Is this an option within VS2013?  I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation. May work for you:

1. In Visual Studio in PROJECT -> Project Properties -> References
2. Make sure you only have Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common Version 11 and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms Version 11
3. In the references I had Version 10 and when I removed those references the ReportViewer Control worked correctly.